# android tabhost tab and view not matching

Tags: android, tabs

I have two tabs in my tabwidget and each tab display a list view.
ay
Initially my first tab is displayed as selected but below list correspond to second tab. 
Once i click the tabs, i am getting correct display.

```
private static final String LIST_TAB_TAG1 = "UpcomingEvents";
private static final String LIST_TAB_TAG2 = "PastEvents";

tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec(LIST_TAB_TAG1)
            .setIndicator(LIST_TAB_TAG1)
            .setContent(new TabContentFactory() {
                public View createTabContent(String arg) {
                    return listView1;
                }
            }));
    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec(LIST_TAB_TAG2)
            .setIndicator(LIST_TAB_TAG2)
            .setContent(new TabContentFactory() {
                public View createTabContent(String arg) {
                    return listView2;
                }
            }));
    tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
```

LIST_TAB_TAG1 is highlighted when this sctivity is launched but the list displayed is listview2. This problem is only when activity starts. Upon clicking tabs its working fine

Can please help me in fixing this. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

I generally use the code given in docs which works fine for me ,try this one .

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost
    TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Resusable TabSpec for each tab

    Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab
    // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, UpcomingEvents.class);
    // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("UpcomingEvents").setIndicator("UpcomingEvents",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.homebutton1)).setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);
    // Do the same for the other tabs
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this,PastEvents.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("PastEvents").setIndicator("PastEvents",
                      getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bank_transaction1))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
  }
```

Comment: here i have listviews to be displayed for each tab. Thats why i have used this method.

Comment: Ok , But above also work for listView you have to set setcontentView for respective list in its activity .